# No Kivy GUI visible during Teamview - Windows to kivy Raspberry Pi GUI

Tags: kivy, teamviewer

I am working on a Smart home which is running on a Raspberry Pi  and I want to have access to my Kivy Gui with Teamviewer. But when I connect to my Pi for example from my MacBook I only see the Pi Desktop running not the GUI.
Is there anything I forgot or is it not possible? OpenGL issue?
Probably there is a smarter way, please tell me.

Comment: I think it is not possible. I had the same experience with VNC. I would try to build a web server with your pi and host a local website https://diyhacking.com/raspberry-pi-web-server/

Comment: or it might still be possible with vnc https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=146749

Comment: There is a whole SE dedicated to RPi https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/. Maybe you can find something useful there.